# Can't access array in Javascript/d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array called `ageNames`. When I print it I get:

> `Array[12]`

When you look at the elements it says:

> ```
> 1: "Blah"
>
> 2: "blah2"
>
> length:12
>
> _proto_:Array[0]
> ```

However, if I say `console.log(ageNames[0])` it says `undefined` (as it does for all elements). And if you do `console.log(ageNames.length)` you get a `0`.

What is going on?

Relevant Code:

```
  var mdata = [];
  var mnames = [];
  var rowID = [];

  var ageNames = [];
  d3.json("whiskey.json", function(error, data) {

  ageNames.push(d3.keys(data[1]).filter(function(key) { return (key !== "Distillery" && key !== "RowID"); }));
data.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d["RowID"] <= 5){
        
    //console.log(mdata);
    mnames.push(d["Distillery"]);
    rowID.push(d["RowID"]);
    //console.log(d);
    mdata.push(d);

    }
    });

 console.log(ageNames);
 console.log(ageNames.length);
```

The first line prints Array[12] and you can look at the individual elements.
The second line prints 0. How can the length be 0?

});

Comment: Can you give us a [fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Maybe the indices are not numeric but strings... We need more code I suppose.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5MQqg/

Comment: @elclanrs, 0x499602D2 yes, and I posted some relevant code.

Comment: It looks like your `console.log` calls are **outside** of the `d3.json` callback. You are trying to access the array *before* it has values, because `d3.json` is *asynchronous*. Move the log calls *inside* the `d3.json` callback. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196 for an explanation of the problem.

Comment: I don't see how the asynchronous part effects the problem. It prints the array of right length Then it prints the length. But the length is wrong.

Comment: Might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196. Fact is that `console.log` is called before the array is even populated.

Comment: It looks like you're pushing an entire array onto `ageNames`. You should be pushing one element at a time, or use `.concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Lars I'm a little confused by your fiddle. So I'll have a guess and see where that gets us. The json data is on the page but you're using `d3.json` to call it from the server (where it isn't 'cause you're using a fiddle).  To get your code to work on the fiddle we can ignore the `d3.json` call, but when you try this out in your development environment remember to wrap it all up in the `d3.json` call as it's asynchronous as pointed out by Felix.

Having said that it looks as though you're trying to create a variable for use in a d3 bar chart using a forEach loop.  I've taken an approach of creating an array of objects in the following code which I *think* will achieve what you want.

```
jsondata.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d.RowID<=5) {
        var el = {
            mnames: d.Distillery,
            rowID: d.RowID
        };
        mdata.push(el);
    }
});
```

You can then access these variables in the usual way, although this seems like a lot of work to create the dataset I *think* you want.  You could just filter the data in the `.data` line, as in

```
.data(jsondata.filter(function (d,i) { return //do some magic filtering stuff; })
```

Anyway I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MQqg/1/) and created a bar chart using the first 5 entries.  I haven't really explained what I've done there, but if you have any questions leave a message.